# Summarise occurence of columns and write their N into a new column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I seem to be stuck trying to summarise the occurence of a given column (`df$fam`). As you can see, it contains unique identifiers for each observation. In some cases, hoewever, these identifiers occur more than once. What I am trying to do is find some way to create a column that shows the number of occurences (`df$fam_N`) for each indidivual observation (i.e. I have to find some way to circumvent `group_by`).

```
df<- df%>% group_by(fam) %>% summarise(fam_N = sum(n())))

> table(df$fam_N)
>    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   11   48 
> 1296  125   97  113  119   56   19    8    3    1    1 


> str(df$fam)
> chr [1:3503] "475124" "574675" "439440" "439440" "465883" 
> "571875" "571921" "571875" "574620" "459136" "387418" "513654" ..`
```

desired output:

```
table(df$fam, df$fam_N) 

475124  1
574675  1
439440  2
439440  2
465883  1
```

Comment: Try `count` from `dplyr` as in `count(mtcars, am)`

Comment: Hi @markus, I can see how my outout would suggest that, but I actually want to assign each observation in my original dataframe their respective N. `count()` already aggregates by each  indivudual `fam`.

Comment: Then you should `left_join`: `left_join(mtcars, count(mtcars, am))`

Comment: aweseome! that does the trick! thank you so much.